# Unable to get update: "Errors were encountered while processing"

Tags: system-installation

I get an error when trying to install an update:

```
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
```

How can I fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Please edit your question and add complete error output.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the cached .deb files doing:

```
sudo apt clean
```

Those packages have already been installed and are not used anymore so you can safely removed them, to either free storage or avoid these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide detailed information about the error nor any log, this may work in your case:

1. Clean pending transactions:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

2. Clean up your APT cache and remove unnecessary dependencies:

> sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove

3. Update the cache and packages:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try purging the package and trying again

```
sudo apt-get purge libperl5.22
sudo apt-get install libperl5.22
```